# Python scraping Websocket datas

Tags: python, websocket, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape websocket datas(frames) from a website using sockjs, in Python but I don't really know how to do that.

URL: ws://example.io/sockjs/wkzeza/websocket

In the web debugger I can see this response headers:

```
Date: Sun, 27 Aug 2017 09:42:15 GMT
Connection: upgrade
Set-Cookie: oWG+Kel2MBo0v9FQK81NvuvBZcUwChaMvG2bsv1Ofs9Q8hHN+PlTn6PolO/8MgFXh2ygqC7A8WsJ7cgZwvpwvsbSp0VCpRHqmYMhGGxr; Expires=Sun, 03 Sep 2017 09:42:15 GMT; Path=/
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HA0gkvrFCF7qjVYIDvSBa5sJKkg=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Server: nginx
CF-RAY: 394e146d34a12f65-MAD
```

Normally with only the response header I can retrieve the datas from the frames, right?

I've tried with this code but I can read the content:

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json

headers = json.dumps({'Date': 'Sun, 27 Aug 2017 09:42:15 GMT',
'Connection': 'upgrade',
'Set-Cookie': 'oWG+Kel2MBo0v9FQK81NvuvBZcUwChaMvG2bsv1Ofs9Q8hHN+PlTn6PolO/8MgFXh2ygqC7A8WsJ7cgZwvpwvsbSp0VCpRHqmYMhGGxr; Expires=Sun, 03 Sep 2017 09:42:15 GMT; Path=/',
'Upgrade': 'websocket',
'Sec-WebSocket-Accept': 'HA0gkvrFCF7qjVYIDvSBa5sJKkg=',
'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate',
'Server': 'nginx',
'CF-RAY': '394e146d34a12f65-MAD'})

ws = create_connection('ws://example.io/sockjs/wkzeza/websocket', header=headers)
response = ws.recv_data_frame()
print(response)

>> [1, <websocket._abnf.ABNF at 0x7efe29aa0da0>]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, finally I've found. The reason was... my lack of knowlegde about websocket and also I've found a really good repo with an example an explanation (https://github.com/oliver006/sockpuppet). With few changes it works perfectly for my case.

Comment: it also solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 7):

Check the traffic in Chrome (or other browser) to see how you should negotiate to beginning the flow of data.
When the negotiation is OK you can do something like:

```
while True:
    ws.recv()
```

Here is an example for up/down WebSocket-traffic in Chrome.

[image]

Just copy the message up and use it in ws.send().
Example:

```
ws.send('''{"H":"publicmaphub","M":"getData","A":[],"I":1}''')
```

The example is from this live view of buses in Norway/Stavanger:
https://www.kolumbus.no/ruter/kart/sanntidskart-internt/?c=58.974238,5.691347,14&lf=all&vt=bus,ferry

(On that page you also need to first get a token through HTTPS, connect with WebSocket and do another HTTPS to start the traffic. After this you can do the ws.recv() and ws.send() combos to start getting data.)